# How can I mutate state inside async block with StreamExt::scan method in Rust?

Tags: rust, async-await, future, lifetime

I'm trying to use scan method from StreamExt. It works perfectly if I have no async block.

```
use futures::{stream, StreamExt};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    stream::iter(1..10)
        .scan(0, |s, i| {
            *s += i;
            futures::future::ready(Some(*s))
        })
        .for_each(|x| async move {
            println!("{:?}", x);
        })
        .await;
}
```

But if I do have `async` block, it doesn't compile.

```
use futures::{stream, StreamExt};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    stream::iter(1..10)
        .scan(0, |s, i| async move {
            *s += i;
            Some(*s)
        })
        .for_each(|x| async move {
            println!("{:?}", x);
        })
        .await;
}
```

Error is:

```
error: borrowed data cannot be stored outside of its closure
  --> src/main.rs:6:36
   |
5  |  /     stream::iter(1..10)
6  |  |         .scan(0, |s, i| async move {
   |  |__________________------____________^
   | ||                  |
   | ||                  ...because it cannot outlive this closure
7  | ||             *s += i;
8  | ||             Some(*s)
9  | ||         })
   | ||_________^ cannot be stored outside of its closure
...   |
12 |  |         })
13 |  |         .await;
   |  |______________- borrowed data cannot be stored into here...
```

How can I solve this issue and mutate state inside an `async` block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't share references across `async` boundaries. As soon as code executes in an `async` context, there is no way to track the lifetimes any more because the compiler doesn't know when the future will complete.

One solution is to use a reference counted smart pointer and internal mutability:

```
use futures::{stream, StreamExt};
use std::cell::Cell;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    stream::iter(1..10)
        .scan(Rc::new(Cell::new(0)), |s, i| {
            let s = s.clone();
            async move {
                s.set(s.get() + i);
                Some(s.get())
            }
        })
        .for_each(|x| async move {
            println!("{:?}", x);
        })
        .await;
}
```

The `s` in the closure argument is an `&mut Rc<Cell<i32>>` which cannot be moved across the `async` boundary. But the cloned version is an `Rc<Cell<i32>>` which *can* be moved there because there are no lifetimes to keep track of.

Answer (score 1):

```rust
use futures::{stream, StreamExt};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    stream::iter(1..10)
        .scan(0, |s, i| {       // s: &mut i32, i: i32
            *s += i;
            let st = *s;        // Dereference `s`, and move the value of `s` to `st`, but the type of
                                // `*s` is i32 which impl Copy trait, so here Copy `*s` value to
                                // the owned `st`.
                                // 
                                // Note: this works only if `s` impl the Copy trait

            async move {        // move the owned i32 st into the async block (copy again)
                                // and also move i into the async block which is copyed too
                Some(st)
            }
        })
        .for_each(|x| {
            println!("{:?}", x);
            async {}
        })
        .await;
}
```

If `s` does not impl the `Copy` trait, you must copy/clone manually by hand:

```rust
use futures::{stream, StreamExt};

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct TT {
    s: i32,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    stream::iter(1..10)
        .scan(TT{s: 0}, |s, i|  {
            s.s += i;
            // let mut st = *s;      // move occurs because `*s` has type `TT`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
            let st = s.clone();      // clone/copy manually
            async move {
                Some(st)
            }
        })
        .for_each(|x| {
            println!("{:?}", x);
            async {}
        })
        .await;
}
```

If you want to change the `s` inside the async block, you must own it via a smart pointer, like `Rc`, or `Arc`. And also need a way to modify the value wrapped by the smart pointer, like `Mutex`, `RwLock` or `Cell`:

```rust
use futures::{stream, StreamExt, lock::Mutex};
use std::sync::Arc;  // Arc or Rc

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    stream::iter(1..10)
        .scan(Arc::new(Mutex::new(0)), |s, i| { // s: &mut Arc<Mutex<i32>>, i: i32
            let s = Arc::clone(s);              // Clone to owned the Arc

            async move {        // move the owned `s` into the async block
                                // and also move i into the async block which is copyed too
                let mut guard = s.lock().await;
                *guard += i;
                Some(*guard)
            }
        })
        .for_each(|x| {
            println!("{:?}", x);
            async {}
        })
        .await;
}
```

Comment: This has a different output from OP's code. Cloning the value means that the original does not get mutated.

Comment: yes. it depends on whether you need the accumulated or the returned/yield value.